# Adding Attachment to email through Outlook (Python)

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to add a .pdf to an email as an attachment but I keep getting this error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

The path is correct and the rest of my email code works perfectly using win32com. I have tried adding the other parameters for Attachments.add but the last two are optional.

```
Msg.Attachments.add(Source = "C:\\Users\User\Desktop\Python\ThisisaTestTitle.pdf", Type=olByValue)
```

Does anyone have experience with this error?

Comment: Try adding dobule backslash for all the items of the path.

Comment: Try to use these backslashes : `/`

Comment: Using "\\" or "/" for all of them doesn't help. I printed the string and it prints as:

     C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\ThisisaTestTitle.pdf

Comment: Try using an `r` in front of the path `r"C://Users//User//Desktop//Python//ThisisaTestTitle.pdf"`.

Comment: That also doesn't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "add" should be capitalized: `Msg.Attachments.Add(...`

Comment: Of course that's all it is....
Here is my working final code setup:
    Msg.Attachments.Add(Source = "{}\\{}".format(os.getcwd(),pdfname))